# >=' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python, function

My teacher gave me a task where I have to make a function where you introduce the number of trips a person has made and the function returns the total amount of money spent in those trips, this code is giving me the error that is the title of this question.

```
def totalviajes(n):
    valor = 30 #value of the average trip
    if totalviajes >= 1 and totalviajes <= 20:
        valor = valor
    elif totalviajes >= 21 and totalviajes <= 30:
        valor = (valor * 20) / 100 #20% discount on trip
    elif totalviajes >= 31 and totalviajes <= 40:
        valor = (valor * 30) / 100 #30% discount
    elif totalviajes > 40:
        valor = (valor * 40) / 100 #40%
    return valor 
 
#Programa principal
x = float(input("Ingrese la cantidad de viajes: ")) #number of trips input
resultado = totalviajes(x)
print(resultado)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing with `n`, the parameter of the function?

Comment: Well, `totalviajes` is the name of your function, and inside the function's body, you are comparing the function `totalviajes` with numbers (1, 20, etc). That's just not doable. Did you mean to compare `n` to the numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Probably, replace `totalviajes` by `n`:

```
def totalviajes(n):
    valor = 30 #value of the average trip
    if n >= 1 and n <= 20:
        valor = valor
    elif n >= 21 and n <= 30:
        valor = (valor * 20) / 100 #20% discount on trip
    elif n >= 31 and n <= 40:
        valor = (valor * 30) / 100 #30% discount
    elif n > 40:
        valor = (valor * 40) / 100 #40%
    return valor
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `totalviajes` (name of function) instead of `n` (input parameter) in your function.

Comment: Oh I see, its such a simple error im so ashamed of myself. Thank you very much for helping me